# How to connect Amazon ECR website connect with Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-ecr

About AWS. I made a docker image. It contains NodeJS website on port 80 and port 80 is exposed. Website needs env variable. I have a domain on route53. How I can connect ECR with Route53?

Upd. Steps what I doing:

1. Move to ECS page and select/clusters page and push Get Started button
2. In Container definition select custom (push configure button).
3. In settings select my image
   [image: container settings]
4. Press Advanced container configuration and set up container's environment variables. All other settings left empty.
   [image: set up env variables]
5. Press Update
6. Rename Task Definition. All other settings left as it is
   [image: task definition settings]
   7.In container service settings select Add load balancer.
   [image: add load balancer]
   8.Set up cluster name as cluster-name-for-my-website

9.Press Create

10. Done. Cluster created.
    [image: cluster created]
11. Move to Route53 and select my hosted zone
12. Select a record with Type A and press Edit
13. Switch record to Load Balancer.
    [image: A record to load balancer]
14. Save.

As result: Browser response 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Comment: You mean ECS, not ECR? Also do you have load balancer for your ECS service?

Comment: No I mean ECR. Typo I have an image. I tried to up with ECS but always got 503 error

Comment: Can you clarify? ECR is image registry. It does not have any ports opened, nor you can't run any website on it. Its just like docker hub.

Comment: @Marcin yes I have an image on ECR. That image contain a website. I want to lift it up, but can't understand what the way I should to choose.

Comment: You have to start by creating [ECS task definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definitions.html). In its `container` section you will be able to provide details of your ECR image.

Comment: I tried but got 503 error all the time. Maybe there is some guide how I should to set it up or something like this...

Comment: If you don't provide exact details how you tried, no one will be able to give you precise answer.  AWS docs on ECS have plenty of tutorials.

Comment: @Marcin topic updated with steps

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct connection between ECR and Route53. ECR is used to store your container images and then in your Task definition you use a link to your container repository to pull and commission that image in your ECS cluster as a service.

You then expose a route from your load balancer to your target (container) using a listener so the internet traffic can query the container. I hope this part is clear.

Please can you check Target groups under your Load balancers section in the console and make sure that the target (container) is showing Healthy. If it is showing multiple instances with Draining status, check that your heath check path is correct under Health check configuration.

Let us know your findings.